# Input form dropdown shows extra space when used in small screen

Tags: html, css

There is a dropdown which lists all the calendar months. When I see the dropdown in large screen, it is aligned properly but when I use the same for mobile screen, it is misaligned. I want the right side of the dropdown to be aligned.

[image]

It works entirely fine when seen on desktop screen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMEjO.png)

Comment: add your html and css code

Comment: set width for dropdown in media query

Comment: This dropdown is a custom control which is used on many screens in my application.For mobile screen, i have just made the font size smaller and  have fixed the width of the div where this control is placed and nothing else.

Comment: @vel Can you please add the exact css line.

Comment: @media(max-width:768px){.selector{width:200px}}

Comment: It gives no effect

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: I have added the image of full desktop screen where the same code works fine

Answer (score 0):

Use  below `dir="rtl"` attribute  for select

See the live demo on js fiddle

[live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5hcngjqc/)

also add this css :

```
    select, option {
    text-align:right !important;   
}
```

Comment: This will just make the dropdown right to left. It won't align